# Flowgear How to send "Any Error" email for a workflow

Tags: flowgear

I'm trying to setup a Single Email node off the "Any Error" event of a Workflow, as indicated in this screenshot:
[image: workflow image]

What I'm unclear about, is how do I get the Exception info (Stack Trace, Message, etc) into the Body of the email to be sent.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flowgear doesn't provide the stack trace but you can inject the error message into an email. Here's an example:

http://flowgear.me/s/VQi9rpQ

For completeness, I should also add that there are some special additional fields available - see http://developers.flowgear.net/kb/Node:Variable_Bar#Reserved_Variables.

Here's an example that uses them:

http://flowgear.me/s/a7dcCeb