# Questions re Flowgear Formatter and Variable bar

Tags: flowgear

Following the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596365) question, I have my Flowgear Email Alert sending an email on Any Error.

Using this formatter Expression:

> Message: {error}
>
> siteId: {siteId}
>
> workflowId: {workflowId}
>
> workflowInstanceId: {workflowInstanceId}
>
> username: {username}
>
> profile: {profile}

and this variable bar mapping:
[image]

I get this result in the email body of the email:

> Message: [Full email error message here]
>
> siteId: [Site id GUID here]
>
> workflowId: {workflowId}
>
> workflowInstanceId: {workflowInstanceId}
>
> username: cloudmonitoring@flowgear.net
>
> profile: Production

Note that while Message, siteId, username and profile are there, the workflowId and workflowInstanceId are not being populated.  What could I have missed?

Also, I see from the documentation that the workflowInstanceId refers to the ID of the task that was executing.  How can I get this translated into a meaningful task name for the email recipient?

Comment: The shared workflow http://flowgear.me/#s/a7dcCeb is doing the right thing for me - all fields are populated.

Are you calling this from a sub-worfklow perhaps?

Comment: Nope...only a single workflow involved.